# HRESULT: 0x8007000B VS Team Explorer Pending Changes/ Commit

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently receiving this message in Visual Studio 2013 Pro when I navigate to the Team Explorer/ Pending Changes window.

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

While it doesn't prevent me from committing it does prevent me from adding work items. I am currently running Windows 8.1 with 64 bit architecture.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried devenv /resetsettings, repair or re-install?

Comment: I just tried it and still no luck.